# ruby rails migrate is not updating database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, migration

I ran into something with a rails project where migrations don't seem to be affecting the database/tables.

Rails 4/ Ruby 2.0 / Sqllite / development version

Previously if I set up a migration, the results would reflect in the database and tables (using an sqlite data browser)

Now, when I create a migration, it runs with an error code of 0 but nothing in the database changes. 
for example, if I set up this migration and run Rake d:migrate, nothing is added to the database.

```
class CreateTestModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

      def up
        create_table :products do |t|
          t.string :name
          t.text :description

          t.timestamps
        end
      end

      def down
        drop_table :products
      end


  end
end
```

rake migrate runs with an error code of 0

> C:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe -e
>   $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift)
>   C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/Rl2/bin/rake db:migrate
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of PDF was here
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::BMP
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of BMP was here
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::JPEG
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of JPEG was here
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::JPG
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of JPG was here
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::GIF
>   C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.4/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of GIF was here
>   == 20151015154920 CreateTestModel: migrating ==================================
>   == 20151015154920 CreateTestModel: migrated (0.0000s) =========================
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

I suspect that perhaps the sql database is locked. I did reboot my laptop by that didn't work either.

NOTE - I had a lot of messed up migrations. I tried to straighten things out by deleting some of the later migrations and unused datatables. Not sure if that is causing the problem.

Comment: so no errors when running `rake:db:migrate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to

```
class CreateTestModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Or

```
class CreateTestModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :products
  end

end
```

Pretty certain your issue is having the up and down methods within a change one.

Then rerun the migration.

Comment: Thank you. You were right. Having the up/down inside the change was the problem.